# Converting correlated subquery with NOT EXIST and MINUS using joins

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to convert the following correlated subquery using NOT EXIST and MINUS into a query without NOT EXISTS operator.

The schema is very simple :

```
Student(Stud_no: Varchar, Stud_name: Varchar, Dept: Varchar)
Membership(Mem_no: Number, Stud_no: Varchar, Fine: Number)
Book(book_no: Number, book_name: Varchar, author: Varchar, Category: Varchar)
Iss_rec(iss_no: Number, iss_date: date, Mem_no: Number, book_no: Number)
```

To find the Mem_no of the students who have borrowed all the books , my query is,

```
SELECT MEM_NO FROM MEMBERSHIP A WHERE NOT EXISTS ((SELECT BOOK_NO FROM BOOK) MINUS (SELECT BOOK_NO FROM ISS_REC B WHERE A.MEM_NO = B.MEM_NO));
```

Now when I try to implement it using joins , I am getting error .

```
SELECT A.MEM_NO FROM MEMBERSHIP A LEFT OUTER JOIN ((SELECT BOOK_NO FROM BOOK) MINUS (SELECT BOOK_NO FROM ISS_REC B WHERE A.MEM_NO = B.MEM_NO)) C ON A.MEM_NO = C.BOOK_NO WHERE C.BOOK_NO IS NULL;
```

Can anyone help me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work as you expect: it will give you list of students which borrowed all books from Book table. It does not contain NOT EXIST nor MINUS (I guess this restriction was for academic purpose only). See it working with same data at  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/19e78/2

```
 select m.stud_no, count(distinct i.book_no) from membership m join    iss_rec i 
 on i.mem_no=m.mem_no
group by m.stud_no
 having count(distinct i.book_no)=(select count(*) from book)
```

Note that this solution assumes there is a referential integrity (so e.g. there cannnot be book_no in iss_rec which is not in book table)

Comment: You might as well use an inner join in this query, as students that haven't borrowed any books are irrelevant.

Comment: this is good .. but  i am looking for a sub-query not a correlated query